# C++ Basic Variable Identification

Tags: c++, integer, logic, typeid

So I'm trying to learn C++ myself and I can't seem to figure out this certain bug in my program. Here's what I have so far. ANyways, it all seems to be working great; I have the user input their variable  via my prompts I set up, but what's tricky for me is determining what kind of integer they are using.As you can see I threw together a few conditionals comparing byte sizes and max/min for each of the int types (signed, unsigned, long, short), but whenever I run the program, even if I don't use an integer or some bizzare number thtat should easily be showing up as a long, my return is always that of a damned a signed int. Can anyone offer me a bit of advice on what next steps I should be taking? I also can't seem to trigger my error message which is supposed to be shown when a number is not entered into the command prompt. Thinking now to fix that, all I have to do is throw in an array list of banned symbols/letters that will trigger the error, right?

```
/*********************************************************************
** Program Filename: int.cpp
** Description: Checks int type and prints various other details
** Input: int
** Output: metadata
*********************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <climits> // redundant, included in iostream
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

/* define global variables */
int myNumber;
string dataType= "";

/*********************************************************************
** Function: Prompt
** Description: Prompts user for value
** Return: Void
*********************************************************************/
void prompt()
{
    /* define local variables*/
    string input = "";

    /* ask for value until valid value is entered, else show error message */
    while (true) {
        /* Pronmpt user */
        cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        /*  get user input */
        getline(cin, input);

        /* add user input value to string buffer */
        stringstream streamNum(input);

        /* check to see if user entered a valid value */
        if (streamNum >> myNumber)
            cout << endl;
            break;
        /* error message if not int */
        cout << "ERROR: Invalid integer, please try again" << endl;
    }
}

/*********************************************************************
** Function: Get int type
** Description: conditionals to assign data type. using online docs for bit length
** Return: Void
*********************************************************************/
void typeID()
{
    if ( sizeof(myNumber) == 4 )
    {
        dataType = "signed";

    } else if ( sizeof(myNumber) == 4 && myNumber >= 0 )
    {
        dataType = "unsigned";

    } else if ( sizeof(myNumber) == 4 && myNumber >> -2147483647 && myNumber << 2147483647 )
    {
        dataType = "long";
    }else if ( sizeof(myNumber) == 2 && myNumber >> -32768 && myNumber << 32767 )
    {
        dataType = "short";
    }else
        cout << "You did not enter a valid integer. Try again soon! "<< numeric_limits<int>::min();
}

/*********************************************************************
** Function: limits
** Description: check max and min of various int types
** Return: Void
*********************************************************************/
void limits()
{
    if ( dataType == "signed" )
    {
        cout << "Maximum Signed Int Value: " << INT_MAX << endl;
        cout << "Minimum Signed Int Value: " << INT_MIN << endl;
    }else if ( dataType == "unsigned" )
    {
        cout << "Maximum Unsigned Int Value: " << UINT_MAX << endl;
        cout << "Minimum Unsigned Int Value: " << 0 << endl;
    } else if ( dataType == "long" )
    {
        cout << "Maximum Long Int Value: " << LONG_MIN << endl;
        cout << "Minimum Long Int Value: " << LONG_MAX << endl;
    }else if ( dataType == "short" )
    {
        cout << "Maximum Short Int Value: " << SHRT_MAX << endl;
        cout << "Minimum Short Int Value: " << SHRT_MIN << endl;
    }
}

/*********************************************************************
** Function: int info
** Description: prints info of user variable
** Return: Void
*********************************************************************/
void info()
{
    /* print details */
    cout << "You entered: " << myNumber << endl;
    cout << "Integer type: " << dataType << endl; /* demangles and prints type operator of user entered int */
}

/*********************************************************************
** Function: main function
** Description: runs program
*********************************************************************/
int main()
{
    prompt();
    typeID();
    info();
    limits();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you've declared `myNumber` as `int`, therefore it is a signed int everytime. You'd actually have to declare the variable as `short myNumber;` or `unsigned myNumber;` if you wanted to change that. The string stream is just going to take the number they entered and try to put it in the POD that you've passed it.

Comment: `sizeof(x)` doesn't depend on the value of `x`.  (And your logic is completely illogical. And you've misspelled `<` and `>`.)

Comment: @RyanP the myNumber variable is supposed to remain as  an int, but is what you're telling me that once declared as an int it is soley an int and a user cant input a long int for example? It is static? Because I believe I am supposed to be writing a function that takes a user input and declares it a long short signed or unsigned based on how we approach it.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Sorry, could you expand on the sizeof? Would that affect the issues I mentioned in the OP? Also come on man, I'm trying my best to teach myself this. What's wrong with my logic? I really want to get on the right path.

Comment: @RyanP I'm looking into typecasting now, that may be able to solve my issue.

Comment: @SamLim It looks you're thinking of the conditions in your if-else sequence as evaluated "simultaneously" and choosing the best match. The first one is checked first, and the others are only computed if the first one is false, and so on.  In other words, your second condition is equivalent to `if (sizeof(myNumber) != 4 && sizeof(myNumber) == 4 && myNumber >= 0 )`. I think you can spot the problem with that one.

Comment: @molbdnilo ah I think I got it, thanks so much. Just to be clear, I should evaluate all of those at the same time in the same statement, right? Rather than having it immediately see it as a signed int

Comment: @SamLim No, I don't think you should do that. It's not clear what you want this program to accomplish. If you want to determine the smallest type that could hold the value, first check the narrow intervals and then the wider ones. (`if (number >= -32768 && number <= 32767) { could be signed short } else if (number >= 0 && number <= 65535) { could be unsigned short } else and so on...`.

Comment: But note that an `int` always has the same size; `sizeof(myNumber)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Gotcha, the sizeof was confusing the hell out of me. Thanks a lot

Comment: `getline` is a C function that knows nothing about `std::cin` and `std::cout`.  You can use it, but you have to ve *very*, *very*, *very* careful to not mix `<<` operator and `getline()` calls on the same input stream, or you'll run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The type of a variable is determined at compilation time by the compiler on analysing how you have declared the variable (so it is not going to change, independently of the values you enter to the program).  You have declared `myNumber` as `int myNumber`, so it is `signed int myNumber;` (the language C++ specifies it this way, no way to make it different), meaning that it can store **only** signed numbers.  If you try to declare it as `unsigned` or `unsigned int`, it will hold **only** unsigned values.  The problem arises if you try to read an `unsigned` variable and input a negative value, as then, the results are undefined (also by definition, even if it sounds as sarcasm :) )